# Dom Traversal using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i access `<h2>` tag. My current selection is a `<span>` element which is child of button. i tried but was only able to get to the parent which is button.

**Please note i have multiple `<Span>` element on the page**

please note i purely need java script since i am using custom java script which is in Google tag manager.

so basically iam using the below code. just a heads up the {{clickelemet}} here is the `<span>` element
<>
    function() {

```
  var el = {{Click Element}}.parentElement.querySelector('h2');

  return el ? el.textContent || el.innerText : undefined;

}
```

---------------HTML elements -----------------------

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                                    <h2>Blockchain – Opportunities &amp; Challenges across Multiple Industries</h2>
                                    <p>It began with Bitcoin, but now it has spread. Blockchain has the potential to radically transform the way industries do business. Here are some examples of success and challenges as blockchain inserts itself into transactions and process.</p>
                                    <button class="panel__link panel__link--btb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel-1">
                                        <i>+</i> <span>Expand article</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: post a working snippet

Comment: instead of using curly braces please give us a real click element id and its corresponding html element.

Comment: Where is the `span` element?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't edit the HTML at all?

Comment: The {{Click Element}}.nodename = Span Element which contains text "Expand article". this is how its referenced in Google tag manager :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
document.querySelector('h2');
```

Retrieves the first `h2` in the DOM

Comment: Hi I have added more information about what iam trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're adding a click event on your button element. If so, then, the click event can also be actually fired on its child elements (ie span ). So, In order to get the button element's parent, you've to check the event.target :

```
document.querySelector('button.panel__link').addEventListener('click', 
    function(e){
      var el, elContent;
      if(e.target.className === "panel__link panel__link--btb"){
         el = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('h2');
         elContent = el ? (el.textContent || el.innerText) : undefined;
      }

});
```

Comment: i will try using the while loop until parent

Answer (score -3):

If you have only one  in your page, use

`getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];`

If you have multiple tags,

```
var parent = document.getElementById('<your-class>');
var child = parent.getElementById('<your-class>')[0];
```

Comment: You can't use class name inside getElementById and also getElementById returns a single HtmlElement not an array.

Comment: You might be thinking of `getElementByClassName`? Also if you know the id, you don't need to look it up within the parent.

Comment: @clabe45 need to traverse up the DOM chain.